# Check record if exist using updateOrCreate and do a math(SUM) if record exist in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a store function that saves array items into my items table and together with that I am trying to check if the product_is is already in my Warehouse1StockSummaries. if still not, I will grab the product_id and its qty, If its there already then I want to ADD the value from the 'stock_in_qty' which is inside the array to the 'qty_in' in my Warehouse1StockSummaries. I hope my explanation make sense to you :)

here's my code.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $items = [];

    for($i=0; $i<= count($input['stock_in_qty']); $i++) {

        if(empty($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['stock_in_qty'][$i])) continue;

        $acceptItem = [
            'order_id' => $input['order_id'][$i],
            'product_id' => $input['product_id'][$i],
            'order_item_id' => $input['order_item_id'][$i],
            'delivery_date' => $input['delivery_date'][$i],
            'company_id' => $input['company_id'][$i],
            'stock_in_qty' => intval($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]),
            'stock_out_qty' => $input['stock_out_qty'][$i],
            'transfer_to' => $input['transfer_to'][$i],
            'delivery_note' => $input['delivery_note'][$i],
            'user_id' => $input['user_id'][$i]  
        ];

        $product_id = $input['product_id'][$i];
        $qty_in = intval($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]);
        // dd($qty_in);


        // ADD stock_in_qty TO QTY_IN ????
        $stockSummary = Warehouse1StockSummaries::updateOrCreate(
            ['product_id' => $product_id ], 
            ['qty_in'     => $qty_in,
             'qty_out' => null
         ]);
        // dd($stockSummary);

        array_push($items, Warehouse1stocks::create($acceptItem));
    }

    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

I check and everything is ok the only missing is the part where I need to grab the value from 'stock_in_qty' and add to 'qty_in' if the product id is already found in Warehouse1StockSummaries. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Does `qty_in` have a default value in your database?

Comment: Hi @RossWilson none. it has no default value it will depend on the value being added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `wasRecentlyCreated` property on the model to determine if the model has just been created or not. If it hasn't then it won't have used `$qty_in` value, this means you could then use the [increment()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#increment-and-decrement) to add to the existing value in the database:

```
$stockSummary = Warehouse1StockSummaries::firstOrCreate(
    ['product_id' => $product_id ], 
    ['qty_in' => $qty_in, 'qty_out' => null]
);

if (!$stockSummary->wasRecentlyCreated) {
    $stockSummary->increment('qty_in', $qty_in);
}
```

Comment: ahh I see may I know where in my code should i put that?

Comment: @Lito Underneath where you're using `updateOrCreate`.

Comment: Hi again @RossWilson it works but Is there a way to add the previous record instead of increment? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Lito You've lost me, what do you mean by add the previous record? I thought you only wanted to create a new record if one didn't already exist?

Comment: apology for that. The 'qty_in' serves as the running total of the quantity of the certain product. so let say in my record I have 600 bottles and then today i will be receiving 200 bottles, I want that 200 to be added to 600.

Comment: @Lito I've updated my answer. You should use `firstOrCreate` instead of `updateOrCreate`.

Comment: yes its working @RossWilson. Thank you so much! :) but may I know why we use firstOrCreate instead of updateOrCreate?

Comment: @Lito `updateOrCreate` will use the values in the second array regardless or whether it is updating or creating, whereas, `firstOrCreate` will only use the values from the second array when it is creating. Since you want to keep the original values if the row exists,`updateOrCreate` is not suitable.

Comment: I got it now Thank you so much for helping me @RossWilson! :)